# How to call the middleware OnMessageActivityAsync in bot framework v4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework, middleware

I have a bot made in framework v4 using c#.i want to call the middleware on OnMessageActivityAsync But unable to. Do we have any way to call the method of middleware on this method.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "call" the middleware? Is it an existing middleware, or something you've developed? Please give more info

Answer (score 0):

I think you could, using dependency injection, get access to the middleware. However, I'd advise against this, it basically breaks the architectural design of what middleware is designed for, I'd think. Perhaps another suggestion is just to move that method into a shared access location, like, for example, a static class, extension method, or similar. Is that possible in your scenario?

Comment: Do you have  a link you can send so I could look into that?

Comment: and you're wanting to call something on the handoffmiddleware, I guess? https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample/blob/master/IntermediatorBotSample/Middleware/HandoffMiddleware.cs

Comment: yes,, can you help me to integrate human handoff feature in my bot...this will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

As Hilton said, I'd recommend against middleware that is only called during `OnMessageAsync()`....it sort of defeats the purpose of middleware. I'd recommend looking into [the experimental Handoff Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/samples/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.HandoffBot). Note that it's experimental and may contain breaking changes at some point.

[Here's the README for the also-experimental Handoff Library](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/experimental/handoff-library).

You can see that instead of using a middleware, it extends the [`Adapter`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/experimental/handoff-library/csharp_dotnetcore/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Handoff/BotFrameworkHttpAdapterWithHandoff.cs).

---

The tompanaa sample is something we used to point to a lot, but as you can see, it's woefully out of date. We'll eventually make either the Handoff library or something like it part of the SDK, but it's on the backburner.

Comment: Their are many issue reported with this link. Do think this link will help for chat with agent(human handoff) ..as did by tompanna?..

Comment: @shivanisingh That repo contains *all* of our samples. There are [few issues with that particular sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+sort%3Aupdated-desc+handoff). But yes, I think it will help a lot. The Tompanna sample is good, too, it's just outdated. The concepts would still work, though, if you wanted to implement the same thing

Comment: do have any solution where live chat with agent feature is working and it not out of date

Comment: @shivanisingh We don't have any current samples other than the one I linked to, no. [Here's one in Node](https://github.com/tdurnford/botframework-human-handoff) that is a *little* more current, but in my opinion, shows a really good way to implement this.